# Redirect On Finish Button On WSS Survey

Tags: sharepoint-designer, wss-3.0

I am trying to redirect to another page when a user finishes a Survey in WSS. I tried to redirect using JS in the PreSaveAction() function but that did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have one page survey, using "Source=URL" querystring parameter when opening the survey will get users redirected to the given URL after finishing the survey.

Comment: What if you have a multiple page survey?

Comment: Actually I would recommend you to try source parameter with multi-page survey, I haven't actually tested, just have read that it wouldn't work.

Comment: I had almost exactly this problem on a WSS 3 survey a while ago on a 1 page survey. Initially I tried to fill in the RedirectUrl property on the Finish and Cancel buttons on the NewForm.aspx but it didn't work correctly - I can't remember what happened though. In the URL, inserting Source=ABC into the querystring works OK. The downside of this approach is that you can't set a separate URL for the Submit and Cancel buttons.